# Stream Closed on Camel ZipSplitter

Tags: apache-camel, zip

I am using a Camel route to split a zip file and process it with the following code:

```
return rb -> rb.from("file:{{inbox}}?recursive=true&readLock=markerFile&delay=5000&antInclude=**/*.zip&move=.done")
            .routeId("Unzip_File_Route")
            .split(new ZipSplitter())
            .streaming()
                .process(new MyFileProcessor())
            .to("file:{{inbox}}?fileName=${header.unzippedPath}")
            .end()
            ;
```

and I am using a zip file to test it but I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
                   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipIterator.getNextElement(ZipIterator.java:125)
                   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipIterator.next(ZipIterator.java:89)
                   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipIterator.next(ZipIterator.java:39)
                   at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter$SplitterIterable$1.next(Splitter.java:249)
                   at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter$SplitterIterable$1.next(Splitter.java:224)
                   at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.run(MulticastProcessor.java:532)
                   at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
                   at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
                   at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
                   at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:398)
                   at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:492)
                   at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:245)
                   at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:206)
                   at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:197)
                   at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:111)
                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
           Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
                   at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:157)
                   at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
                   at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
                   at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
                   at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
                   at java.base/java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:182)
                   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully(ZipInputStream.java:418)
                   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:280)
                   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:124)
                   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipIterator.getNextEntry(ZipIterator.java:139)
                   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.zipfile.ZipIterator.getNextElement(ZipIterator.java:110)
                   ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I am using Debian to run this code.
Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was elsewhere.
The stream obtained in `ZipSplitter` [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/b92eef9ee18604e6e1d463f34f792b2eb73c6560/components/camel-zipfile/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/zipfile/ZipSplitter.java#L36) was not closed but null from the beginning due to missing `TypeConverter`.

Adding the following plugin added those converters in the jar and solved my problem:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.camel}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-fatjar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```